# Combine a Function and a Predicate in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, predicate, functional-interface

In `isBigOrder` method if  sum prices of products in order is bigger than 1000 it must return true. how can I write it using java 8? I wrote the sum part but I couldn't complete it.

```
public Function<Order, Boolean> isBigOrder() {

        Function<Order, Optional<Long>> sum = a -> a.getProducts()
                .stream()
                .map(P -> P.getPrice())
                .reduce((p1,p2)->p1+p2);

        Predicate <Optional<Long>> isBig =  x -> x.get() > 1000 ;

        return ????;
    }
```

In case other classes are needed:

```
enum OrderState { CONFIRMED, PAID, WAREHOUSE_PROCESSED, READY_TO_SEND, DELIVERED }

enum ProductType { NORMAL, BREAKABLE, PERISHABLE }

public class Product {
    private String code;
    private String title;
    private long price;
    private ProductState state;
    private ProductType type;

    //all fields have getter and setter

    public Product price(long price) {
        this.price = price;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Order {

    private String code;
    private long price;
    private String buyyer;
    private OrderState state;
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    //all fields have getter and setter

    public Order price(long price) {
        this.price = price;
        return this;
    }

    public Order product(Product product) {
        if (products == null) {
            products = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        products.add(product);
        return this;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why would you return `Function<Order, Boolean>`? What's the advantage over returning a `boolean` and putting the method in `Order` class?

Comment: Your `if (products == null) {
            products = new ArrayList<>();
        }` statement is entirely obsolete, as you are always initializing the `products` field with an `ArrayList`. Declare it `final` if you want to be sure that no-one ever overwrites it with `null`…

Comment: And as another a side note, `a -> { long value = 0; for(Product p: a.getProducts()) { value += p.getPrice(); if(value>1000) return true; } return false; }` is not streamy, but more efficient, as it can return immediately when the threshold is exceeded instead of unnecessarily continuing with processing all elements.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need the `Predicate`. Just calculate the sum and check whether it's > 1000.

```
public Function<Order, Boolean> isBigOrder() {
    return o -> o.getProducts()
                 .stream()
                 .mapToLong(Product::getPrice)
                 .sum() > 1000;
}
```

Or, as Holger commented, the `Predicate` interface is a more suitable functional interface when you want to implement a function with a single argument that returns a `boolean`:

```
public Predicate<Order> isBigOrder() {
    return o -> o.getProducts()
                 .stream()
                 .mapToLong(Order::getPrice)
                 .sum() > 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you cannot combine the two functions at the state of writing, for example, because they come from different places, you could combine them as follows:

```
public static Function<Order,Boolean> combine(
    Function<Order, Optional<Long>> f
,   Predicate <Optional<Long>> pred
) {
    return a -> pred.test(f.apply(a));
}
```